# Is it possible to render a game level like the old Baldur's Gate ga

Tags: orthographic

So I'm wondering if it's possible to create the scene for a level like in Baldur's Gate (where some of the maps can be 6000x3000). The thing is, they're all at a constant look-down angle and position no matter where you are on the map (effectively an isometric map, although not a tiled one)

Would creating an orthographic camera be sufficient for this ? If not, would it be possible to traverse the camera over the terrain and stitch renders together somehow ?

In case it's not obvious (as if!) I'm new to Blender, although I've written a fair amount of code in my time...

[edit]
So apparently I’m supposed to add new information to the post, not reply inline :) To clarify, what I’m trying to do is render a large isometric-perspective (well dimetric really, I guess) map, using world-creator to create the mesh, and blender to do an orthographic-camera render.

I’ve been doing some more reading and it seems if I set the camera look-down angle to 30 degrees, I get my nice 2:1 dimetric scale, and I can use a sun lamp to give consistent shadows across the scene.

I’m still having mental difficulties grasping that it could, in fact, be this easy :) Those are bound to be famous last words :)

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you're making; An image? A 3D environment? Are you asking if Blender can render a 6000x3000 image? (That size seems pretty well within reason)

Comment: So you want to know how big blender can render with orthogonal camera? And that rendered image is just for map like asset in your game?

Comment: Edited the main post to reply to both of these question. Tx :)